# ROS furte gazebo_ros_camera does not publish topics

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Good evening,

I'm a little bit confused about the new configuration of the sensor
controller. Now they are embedded in plugin structure. I'd like to run a
camera device on gazebo ROS fuerte (Ubuntu 12.04).

My simple launch file is

```
<launch> <arg name="paused" default="true"/> <arg
name="use_sim_time" default="false"/> <arg name="gui" default="true"/>

<group if="$(arg use_sim_time)"> </group>

<group if="$(arg paused)"> <node name="gazebo" pkg="gazebo" type="gazebo"
args="-u $(find gazebo_worlds)/worlds/empty.world" respawn="false"
output="screen"/> </group>

<group if="$(arg gui)"> <node name="gazebo_gui" pkg="gazebo" type="gui"
respawn="false" output="screen"/> </group>

<!-- send the erratic robot XML to param server -->
<param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro.py
'./camera.xacro'" />

<!-- push robot_description to factory and spawn robot in gazebo -->
<node name="spawn_robot" pkg="gazebo" type="spawn_model"
      args="-param robot_description
            -urdf
            -z 0.1
            -model robot_description"
      respawn="false" output="screen" />

<!-- start robot state publisher -->
<node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="state_publisher"
name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen" >
    <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="50.0" />
</node>
</launch>
```

where 'camera.xacro' file (I know that is deprecated but it is trivial to
convert it in urdf ) is

```
<robot xmlns:controller="&lt;a href=" http:=""
playerstage.sourceforge.net="" gazebo="" xmlschema=""
#controller"="">http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="HummingBird">

<xacro:property name="id" value="0"/> <xacro:property name="PI"
value="3.141592653589793"/> <xacro:property name="HALF_PI"
value="1.570796326794897"/>

<xacro:property name="body_size" value="0.080"/> <xacro:property
name="body_mass" value="0.300"/> <material name="body_color"> <color
rgba="1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0"/> </material>

<gazebo reference="base_link"> <material>Gazebo/Red</material> </gazebo>
<link name="base_link"> <visual> <geometry> <box size="${body_size}
${body_size} ${body_size}"/> </geometry> <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
</visual>

<inertial>
  <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
  <mass value="${body_mass}" />
  <inertia ixx="1e-5"  ixy="1e-10"  ixz="1e-10" iyy="1e-5" iyz="1e-10"
izz="1e-5" />  
</inertial>

<collision>
  <geometry>
    <box size="${body_size} ${body_size} ${body_size}"/>
  </geometry>
</collision>
</link>

<gazebo reference="base_link"> <sensor name="camera" type="camera"
always_on="1" update_rate="30" visualize="true"> <camera> <horizontal_fov
angle="1.57079633"/> <image width="640" height="480" format="R8G8B8"/>
<clip near="0.1" far="100"/> </camera> <plugin name="camera_plugin"
filename="libgazebo_ros_camera.so"> <alwayson>true</alwayson>
<imagetopicname>image_raw</imagetopicname>
<camerainfotopicname>camera_info</camerainfotopicname>
<updaterate>30.0</updaterate> <cameraname>overhead_camera</cameraname>
<framename>overhead_camera_frame</framename> <cxprime>320.5</cxprime>
<cx>320.5</cx> <cy>240.5</cy> <hackbaseline>0</hackbaseline>
<focallength>320.000101</focallength> <distortionk1&gt;0.0<
distortionk1&gt;="" <distortionk2&gt;0.0<="" distortionk2&gt;=""
<distortionk3&gt;0.0<="" distortionk3&gt;="" <distortiont1&gt;0.0<=""
distortiont1&gt;="" <distortiont2&gt;0.0<="" distortiont2&gt;="" <=""
plugin=""> </sensor> </gazebo> </robot>
```

The real problem is that the launch file is correct and everything works.
The problem is when I want to show the image (I assume that the topic name
for the camera is image_raw or camera/image_raw) but any kind of this topic
exist (I checked also with rostopic list).

Does anyone try the same plugin? The name is gazebo_ros_camera. If it is
possible, paste your code.

Thanks in advance,

Neostek

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/73/ros-furte-gazebo_ros_camera-does-not-publish-topics/) by [Neostek](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48/neostek/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-10-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I'm using groovy, and this is a partial solution, but there is data on

```
rosrun gazebo gztopic view /gazebo/default/camera/link/camera/image
```

after running gazebo with this following world file

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sdf version="1.3">
  <world name="default">
    <physics type="ode">
      <gravity>0 0 -9.8</gravity>
      <ode>
        <solver>
          <type>quick</type>
          <dt>0.001</dt>
          <iters>40</iters>
          <sor>1.0</sor>
        </solver>
        <constraints>
          <cfm>0.0</cfm>
          <erp>0.2</erp>
          <contact_max_correcting_vel>100.0</contact_max_correcting_vel>
          <contact_surface_layer>0.0</contact_surface_layer>
        </constraints>
      </ode>
    </physics>
    <!-- A global light source -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <!-- A ground plane -->
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://create</uri>
      <pose>0 0 0.5 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>

    <include>
      <uri>model://camera</uri>
      <pose>0 0 1 0 0 0</pose>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

I'm still working on getting the ROS topic published.. the [process](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/using_the_ros_plugins#CAMERA) exists, but I'm hoping there's another way. It should be possible to include the camera model from the database and then add the ROS plugin (since all users of cameras will not be ROS users).

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/43/sl-remy/) with karma: 319 on 2013-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0